# Android - When to write to database, to prevent writing extensively

Tags: android, sql-server, database

When should I write to the Database? When this might be massively called.

My Layout looks like this: [image: Score List Item]

Every time the user clicks on the button the number updates. If at this moment the value would be written to the database, it could be written a 100 times.

So I wonder if I should write in `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` or maybe somewhere else.

Comment: I think `onPause` is the best place to call it if you write values to your database extensively. It it almost guaranteed to get called, the only time when it's not is when your app crashes

Answer (score 1):

You should write it when you need it saved.

If you are required to follow up on all numbers generated, write them all.
If not, write onDestroy()

It all depends on the purpose of saving the data.

Comment: `onDestroy` is worst place to do anything because is not guaranty to call, use `onPause` or `onStop`